# How to update text in a textbox by changing item of a dropdownlist in the same listview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have an asp.net paget with an ListView. I want automatically change the text of an textbox when a certain value in a dropdownlist of the same listview- row is selected. 
How to I fire the event and change the textbox.text of the same row as the dropdownlist?

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759568/simple-display-with-onchange-event-on-textbox

Comment: This is a solution without listview and does not solve my problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Was just a comment to helpful, not an answer :) Part of your question was `How do I fire the event` - there is an `OnChange` event that you can fire to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by casting the `NamingContainer` of the `sender` back to a ListView DataItem and use FindConrol to locate the TextBox.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Item A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item C</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a dropdownlist
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;

    //get the current listview dataitem from the dropdownlist namingcontainer
    ListViewDataItem item = ddl.NamingContainer as ListViewDataItem;

    //find the textbox in the item with findcontrol
    TextBox tb = item.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

    //set the text
    tb.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```